# JSF2 Managed Bean Reference Problem: CDI Injection?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, cdi

I have a managed bean called:

```
@ManagedBean(name="configBean")
@SessionScoped
public class configBean implements Serializable {
```

that instantiates a class/bean (that isn't a managed bean its a standard class):

```
com.package.class variableName = new com.package.class();
```

& a number of objects are created/set from this class eg:

```
variableName.setCached( true );
```

And I have another bean, which at the moment is simply called:

```
@ManagedBean(name="testBean")
@SessionScoped
public class testBean implements Serializable {
```

& basically I want to reference/implement the '`variableName`' instantiation in my testBean like so:

```
    if( !( variableName.isCached() ) )
     {
        System.out.println( "cry yourself to sleep foo..");
     }
  else
    { 
        System.out.println( "your not as useless as you look");
    }
```

From what I've seen it looks as though Bean Injection is what I am looking for? However I haven't got it working yet so was hoping someone could knock-up a quick example so I know I am on the right lines!

Cheers

Comment: Consider `System.out.println("variableName.isCached(): " + variableName.isCached())` instead.  Less cute but more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both `configBean` and `testBean` are managed beans you can reference them like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name="testBean")
@SessionScoped
public class testBean implements Serializable { 

   @ManagedProperty(value="#{configBean}")
   private ConfigBean configBean;

   ....

   ... configBean.getVariableName().isCached()...
}
```

Comment: Hmmm this is what I thought & I've been playing around with, but I'm getting a 'Cant instantiate class: com.package.testBean.', which the stack trace says: 'Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException'.. any ideas?

Comment: Then your constructor in testBean has a problem (which should be called TestBean btw, conventions are a good thing)

Answer (score 0):

Following code in testBean

```
private configBean configBean;

@ManagedProperty(value="configBean")
public configBean getConfigBean()
{
    return configBean;
}

public void setConfigBean(configBean configBean)
{
    this.configBean = configBean;
}
```

Then you can access variableName with

```
configBean.getVariableName();
```